# Sencha Touch - What is wrong with this Model?

Tags: model, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Following this [post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-eclipse-plugin-tips-tricks) I was able to get the abc project up and running in eclipse:

[image]

In Eclipse I made a model called Temperature:

[image]

In the app.js I added a single line for the models:

[image]

Which causes this when I refresh the page:

[image]

So I figure something is wrong with the model, as when I comment out the line `models: ['Temperature']` the page loads correctly.

Comment: Try removing the extra comma in the `fields` property. You only have one field inside that. So, you don't need to put that comma there. Try removing that and see how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the model definition reference abc instead of app

So

`Ext.define('abc.model.Temperature', {`

Also make sure the case of abc is all lower case to match the application name.

And make sure your Temperature.js file exists in the abc/app/model/ folder

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You given application name as `abc`, but you defined model as `App.model.Temperature`

**Solution**

you should change model definition as `abc.model.Temperature` or change the application name as `App`.

**Note**

Lets say you given application name as `AppName`.

you should define

mode as - `AppName.model.TemperatureModel`

store as - `AppName.store.TemperatureStore`

controller as  - `AppName.controller.TemperatureController`

view as - `AppName.view.TemperatureView`

Every `model,controller,store and view` should follow this.

**Where**

`AppName` - name of the application

`model/store/controller/view` - 
location of the class (TemperatureModel is with in model folder and TemperatureStore is within store folder)

`TemperatureStore/TemperatureStore/TemperatureController/TemperatureView` - name of the class (you can give what ever name you want but name should match file name).

**Reference**

[Ext.app.Application](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application)